# Social Icons: To sprite or not to sprite?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a HTML/CSS template, and I'm going to implement the following social media icons:

http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/41-social-media-icons-png/

They come as 41 seperate .png files. I want to include them into my template using CSS classes, for easy usage like so:

```
<i class="icon-twitter"></i>
<i class="icon-facebook"></i>
```

Now the question is, should I refer to each icon as a separate file in my CSS classes, or should I consolidate all 41 icons into one sprite and adjust the background position for each class (CSS sprites technique)?

It is quite obvious that probably nobody using my theme will use 41 social media icons on his website (hopefully). I would say on the average site, about 3 or 4 icons are used at once. So this makes me wonder if it makes sense at all, to use the sprites technique when only ever about one tenth (4 of 41) is used.

The file sizes for the single files average at about 2kb per file.
The sprite I created is 42kb in size.

What is the best solution for this scenario?

Also: Does it matter how the icons in a sprite are distributed? I just made 2 columns and 21 rows of icons. It might as well be one column and 41 rows, or 6 columns and 7 rows.

Cheers

Comment: why not start using monochromic iconset from Font Awesome?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you could also create two classes where one class is for light backgrounds and one for darker backgrounds (like Bootstrap). `<i class="theme-dark ico-facebook">&nbsp;</i>` vs `<i class="theme-light ico-facebook">&nbsp;</i>`

Comment: Zlatan: Because I like colored icons :) But thank you for pointing me to Font Awesome. I didn't know that this existed. Might be a good alternative to Glyph Icons.
estrar: Those icons work well on all backgrounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put them all into a sprite.  There are generators that exist to make it really easy to do as well.

Combining them into a sprite will reduce the number of HTTP requests.

http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

Comment: True, it is indeed better and for sure less requests than without using it.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a template you're building I'd suggest provding two options for users.

They could use one sprite which contains the most popular icons such as Facebook, Twitter, YouTube etc.

And another sprite which contains all of the icons.

Then let users of your template choose which sprite to use with the template.

Your CSS can be the same for whatever sprite is used if you include the "most popular icons" in the same layout as the top of the sprite with the whole lot of them in it.

The basic principal is to have as few http requests as possible and doing it this way will result in the target of one http requests but a smaller file size and an optional larger one.

Answer (score 1):

Make one class for the general sprite container.

Make individual classes for positioning the sprite. How they're arranged doesn't really matter. The idea is to reduce HTTP requests.